# Openshift python gear wont deploy

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I have a problem with my most recent openshift gear , i get the python error errno 13 , Permission denied. I have checked around on here and found that most people who have gotten the same issue have just forgot the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement before the `app.run()`, but i still have the same issue. According to the log on openshift, the error seems to be rooting from the socket.py built in to python.

This is my second gear on openshift and both this and my first one is built using flask. The first one works just fine but my second one wont work ...

**This is the error message I get in the python log from openshift:**

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 24, in <module>
app.run()
File "/var/lib/openshift/54d242655973ca23980001d1/python/virtenv /lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 617, in run_simple
inner()
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 599, in inner
passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 408, in make_server
passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 334, in __init__
HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

EDIT 2:
So i changed the ip to OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP but the errorlog looked exactly the same. This is my wsgi.py code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

def run_gevent_server(app, ip, port=8080):
    from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer((ip, port), app).serve_forever()

def run_simple_httpd_server(app, ip, port=8080):
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    make_server(ip, port, app).serve_forever()

from server import app as application

#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = 8080
    zapp = impo.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')

    try:
        run_gevent_server(application, ip, port)
    except:
        run_simple_httpd_server(zapp.application, ip, port)
```

Comment: The user running the app lacks privileges to listen on the port. Find out which ports openshift allows you to use or contact them.

That is not a programming question for stackoverflow, but a helpdesk question for your service provider.

Comment: Yeah i did however turn to Openshift support at first , but they didnt help me at all ... They just told me to go here and post a question .. but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What port/ip address are you using?  You must bind to port 8080 of your openshift ip address, you can't bind to 127.0.0.1, it is not allowed.

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP']
    port = 8080
    zapp = impo.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')

    try:
     run_gevent_server(application, ip, port)
    except:
     run_simple_httpd_server(zapp.application, ip, port)

Comment: Holy s** that didnt get formatted correctly , but that is my entry point

Comment: SSH into your application and run "env | grep IP", i don't think that OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP is correct anymore.

Comment: It return OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP and i still have the same problems when i fix the code :(

Comment: Can you update the question you posted with the new code & errors?